# ListView repeatable background creates whitespace

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to make an application with repeatable background in a listview, but i have some trouble with whitespace between the repeatable image. Why is this? And how can I fix this?

Is there another way to create repeatable background?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, parent, false);
        List<Events> r = getEvent();
        Events e = r.get(position);

        LoaderImageView image = (LoaderImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tittel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView ingress = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        tittel.setText(e.getEventName().toString());
        ingress.setText(e.getIngress().toString());
        image.setImageDrawable(e.getThumbnail().toString());



        Resources res = getResources();
        BitmapDrawable background = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.almanakk_bg);
        background.setTileModeY(TileMode.REPEAT);

        row.setBackgroundDrawable(background);




        return row;
    }
```

[image: ListView with repeatable background]
Almanakk background image:
[image: almanakk_bg]
main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    >
</ListView>
```

Event_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <no.havis.utils.LoaderImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_margin="3dp"/>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="app_theme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/TransparentListView</item>
    <item name="android:expandableListViewStyle">@style/TransparentExpandableListView</item>
</style>

<style name="TransparentListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="TransparentExpandableListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ExpandableListView">
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: please post your xml containing listview and listitem's layout(if you customized it too).And are you sure,your drawable doen't have transperancy in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is transparency in your drawable. Use this image instead:
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is because of Draw 9 patch tool from Android SDK. Removed the whitespace and that worked. Thank you

Comment: Yes.But making 9-patch doesn't add space in your image,neither it creates problem.Problem was because your original image was having transparency into it.Anyways,accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
create drawable bg.xml file 

<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />

and in your activitypage .xml write like this

  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgorund="@drawable/bg" > 
   </ListView>
```

Comment: This would work, but the background should scroll with the content, not a static background. Thank you though.

Comment: then once try like this set list view background   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
and in outer layout set your background whatever you want.